# Jenkins Plugin - Add Table to SideView

Tags: javascript, css, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I am trying to create a table on the left side of the Jenkins page that would list occupied resources (in my case, Virtual Machines that are in use) - I can't figure out how to access the table. No other plugins seem to manipulate that area, and the closest one (Sidebar Link Plugin) adds actions (links) so that does not help me.
Does anyone have any idea?

**Edit**
I've found out that you would need to use xmlns:l="/lib/layout", and should write into "<l:side-panel>". However, it does not seem to do anything so far. It does not even throw an exception or any failure in compilation.

**Edit 2**
I've more or less given up on the idea, instead I'll just create a floating JavaScript/CSS window on the left side. This can be achieved easily by using the "Simple Theme" plugin, and using JS and CSS files to inject the data you want presented anywhere.
In case you are interested in the CSS and JS, I will post an example.

CSS

```
.class-name
{
    position:fixed;
    background:#C0C0C0;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:20%;
    z-index:1000;
}
class-name h3
{
    display:block;
    margin:0 0.5em;
}
```

JS

```
window.onload = function()
{
    window.document.body.onload = CreateTable();
};  

function CreateTable()
{
    var main_table = document.getElementById("main-table");
    var row = main_table.insertRow(0);
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    cell.innerHTML = '<div class="class-name"><h3>Example Title</h3></div>';
}
```

Note that I would still love to know the answer to my original question, if anyone finds out how to do so.